# Слайдер Счетчик

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

Всем привет Друзья))вопрос!!
Как реализовать вот такой счетчик в slick слайдере?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сам слайдер как реализовал?

Comment: @Air это ж плагин slick, написано

Comment: у вас же там есть событие `afterChange`, в чем сложность его обработать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Общее число изображений вы должны знать во время генерации страницы, так что оно генерится на стороне сервера.

Для изменения же текущего номера слайда обработайте событие `afterChange`, одним из параметров которого является номер текущего слайда. нумерация с нуля.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({    
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,    
  });

  $(".slider").on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
     $("#cp").text(currentSlide + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div>your content 1</div>
  <div>your content 2</div>
  <div>your content 3</div>
</div>

<div><span id="cp">1</span>/3</div>
```