# Нумерация слайдов в slick slider

Tags: html, jquery, slick.js, slider-slick.js

У меня есть слайдер написанный на slick slider(там есть клавиши переключения, но речь не о них). У меня в макете есть цифры переключения слайдера(картинка ниже будет :)). Там правда серым цветом не очень видно, но там 3/3. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Ниже прилагаю код, который уже имеется. И нужно ли что-то писать в HTML? Эти цифры допустим и как их оформить?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.carousel__inner').slick({
   infinite: true,
   speed: 500,
   prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><img src="../img/arrow-prev.png"></button>',
   nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><img src="../img/arrow-next.png"></button>',
 });
});
```

Comment: там по умолчанию есть нумерация надо в js написать dots: true

Comment: Там будут точки, но не цифры(

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Слайдер Счетчик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/761517/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba)